# Issues stepping into MFC methods with VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I'm not sure why I am getting these. I just migrated my dev machine to Windows 8 and it's a new installation of Visual Studio 2008. I'm debugging my C++/MFC project and when I try to step into a method as such:

```
CString str = L"Test string";
func1(str);   //Stepping into this method with F11

void func1(LPCTSTR pStr)
{
}
```

I get this window:

[image]

It used to work before. What is missing now?

Answer (score 0):

When I do the same thing, my debugger steps into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include`. Check that the VC folders are all set up correctly, go to Tools\Options in VS2008, expand `Projects and Solutions`, select `VC++ Directories` and choose `Source files` in the "Show directories for:" combo -- my entries are:

- $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\src\mfc
- $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\src\mfcm
- $(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\src\atl
- $(VCInstallDir)crt\src

Comment: Thanks. I checked, but you know, mine has the exact same settings. Just curious if it matters -- I installed VS 2010 and an evaluation copy of VS 2012 after I installed my VS 2008?

Comment: I have installed VS2012 after installing VS2008, it doesn't seem to affect my VS2008 settings -- did you install VS2008 to non-default folders? What happens in the debugger if you select the proper folder where atlcomcli.h is located? [%VCINSTALLDIR%\atlmfc\include]

Comment: No, I installed in the default folder. Or, I should say, I did not change anyhting. As for manually specifying the folder when prompted, it will work for that particular project.